# Get Emails out of a file using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application that Read a file and get emails out of it. I ran my application using threads but my app dosn't get better in performance... What is my problem?

Using Threads (takes 54 sec):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\15.txt");

Regex regx = new Regex(@"([\w\-\.]+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([\w\-]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))");
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();

    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        var mc = regx.Matches(line);

        if (mc.Count != 0)
            foreach (Match item in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }
    }));

    th.Start();
}
```

Normal Code (takes 54 sec):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\15.txt");

Regex regx = new Regex(@"([\w\-\.]+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([\w\-]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}))");
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();

    var mc = regx.Matches(line);

    if (mc.Count != 0)
        foreach (Match item in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your time reading the file from disk dwarfs the regex processing time

Comment: The problem is that you're bound by disk IO, not by computation resources.

Comment: when I remove regex codes, Reading file takes 5 sec.. I think it's not disk reading.. `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\15.txt"); 
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
 var line = sr.ReadLine();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using threads by itself does not make your application faster. In this case in the initial situation you have one thread doing all work. In the next situation you have the first thread starting a thread for doing the work. But you still have only one thread processing and your initial thread waiting till the processing is ready. If you want to make it faster, you need to find parts you can do parallel.

Comment: when I remove regex codes, Reading file takes 5 sec.. I think it's not disk reading.. `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\15.txt"); 
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
 var line = sr.ReadLine();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Creating and starting a thread is a costly operation. Having one per RegEx is probably not cost effective. Calling the RegEx is to cheap to warrant an extra thread for it.

Your disk reading will probably even costlier in terms of time spent so that any benefit that threading *might* have is gone anyway.

Comment: when I remove regex codes, Reading file takes 5 sec.. I think it's not disk reading.. `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\15.txt"); 
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
 var line = sr.ReadLine();
}`